# How to build a dynamic ID click function that depends on a variable generated within the function [jQuery]?

Tags: jquery, html, function, dynamic, click

I am trying to build a jQuery click funktion that uses a dynamic ID and can be applied to an html button that is generated within the click function so i don't have to duplicate the code unnecessarily. Unfortunately the code just seems to work for the first iteration. Here's my code snippet:

```js
var rowCount = parseFloat($('#sonstige_zahlungsströme tbody').length);
console.log(rowCount);

$('#zahlungsstrom_hinzufügen_' + rowCount).click(function() {
  var rowCountPlus = rowCount + 1
  var styleFormatCashFlowStartDate = '<input type="text" style="width: 200px; padding: 5px;" id=\"startdatum_' + rowCountPlus + '\" placeholder="Startdatum" onfocus="(this.type=\'date\')" onblur="(this.type=\'text\')">';
  var styleFormatCashFlowTargetDate = '<input type="text" style="width: 200px; padding: 5px;" id=\"enddatum_' + rowCountPlus + '\" placeholder="Enddatum" onfocus="(this.type=\'date\')" onblur="(this.type=\'text\')">';
  var styleFormatCashFlowPayment = '<input type="text" style="width: 200px; padding: 5px;" id=\"zahlung' + rowCountPlus + '\" placeholder="Zahlung [€/Monat]">';

  jQuery('#sonstiger_zahlungsstrom_' + rowCount).after('<tbody id=\"sonstiger_zahlungsstrom_' + rowCountPlus + '\"><td>' + styleFormatCashFlowStartDate + '</td><td>' + styleFormatCashFlowTargetDate + '</td><td>' + styleFormatCashFlowPayment + '</td><td><button id=\"zahlungsstrom_hinzufügen_' + rowCountPlus + '\">&#10010;</button></td><td><button id=\"zahlungsstrom_entfernen_' + rowCountPlus + '\">&times;</button></td></tbody>');

  //$('#zahlungsstrom_hinzufügen_'+rowCount).hide()

  rowCount = parseFloat($('#sonstige_zahlungsströme tbody').length);
  console.log(rowCount);
```

```html
        <h4><b>Sonstige Zahlungsströme</b></h4>
        <table id="sonstige_zahlungsströme">
            <tbody id="sonstiger_zahlungsstrom_1">
                <td><input type="text" style= "width: 200px; padding: 5px;" id="startdatum_1" placeholder="Startdatum" onfocus="(this.type='date')" onblur="(this.type='text')"/></td>
                <td><input type="text" style= "width: 200px; padding: 5px;" id="enddatum_1" placeholder="Enddatum" onfocus="(this.type='date')" onblur="(this.type='text')"/></td>
                <td><input type="text" style= "width: 200px; padding: 5px;" id="zahlung_1" placeholder="Zahlung [€/Monat]"/></td>
                <td><button id="zahlungsstrom_hinzufügen_1">&#10010;</button></td>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

I declared a global variable (var rowCount) ahead of the function that should be updated at the end of the function when executed. After the first iteration, the click function adds some html to a table and the variable rowCount at the end of the function increases correctly by one unit.

Now that the global variable should have increased by one unit I expected the click function to be triggered when clicking on the new button that was generated within the function and has the same ID like the first one except for the rowCount variable increased by one unit.

Can someone give my a hint what's wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Firstly incremental `id` attributes is an anti-pattern. Don't use them. Use common classes and then traverse the DOM from the element that raises an even to find the related content. Within a `table` this is absolutely trivial to achieve. If you could provide a working example of the above code (including the HTML and relevant CSS) we can ive you an example of how to do this. Secondly, you're not adding an `tr` elements within the multiple `tbody` you append...

Comment: ... Lastly, having so much HTML in JS string literals is not a good idea as it ties the JS and UI too closely together. I'd suggest using templates (or at least hidden elements) which you clone and append when necessary

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add an:

```
onClick(myFunction(this));
```

and then create a function:

```
function myFunction(elem) {
   jQuery(...);
}
```

for me that worked pretty well.